# How to obtain timestamp for every record in the table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table 
   age_display(id int, age int)

I do the following transaction

```
   begin;
   insert into age_display values(1,20);insert into age_display values(2,40);
   commit;
```

Now I want the tabe to display:

```
  ID | Age| Time inserted
  01   20    timex( HH:MM:SS format)
  02   40    timex(HH:MM:SS format)
```

AL I want to ahow is that the multiple inserts belong to the same tx

How do I do the above ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `current_timestamp`, which is defined to return the same timestamp for all calls in a transaction.

```
ALTER TABLE age_display
ADD COLUMN time_inserted timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```

Note that all existing rows will get the timestamp when the `ALTER TABLE` is run.